# using sqlite for a windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I want to use sqlite db in my windows phone 8 app.

I am have come across a [blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/03/12/using-the-sqlite-database-engine-with-windows-phone-8-apps.aspx) which I am following to use sqlite in my app.

The version I have downloaded for SQLite for Windows Phone is 3.8.0. Also I have downloaded sqlite-net-wp8 project from [GITHUB](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8).

The problem I am facing is that while including this sqlite-net-wp8 prject in my WP8 app solution, its giving an error

```
Unable to read the project file Sqlite.vcxproj
```

Also it says,

```
the imported project C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WP80\3.8.0.2\DesignTime\Common Configuration\Neutral\SQLite.QP80.props not found
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Hope this link helps as it is from MsDn

[Sqlite for windows phone 8](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671)

Comment: I am following the steps given in the link but it failing in the step     `You will need to right click on the solution file and select add existing solution. `

Comment: Gimme a Second ill check

Comment: I Got another warning

(warning if the sqlite-net-wp8 does not use the same version of SQLite for windows phone you will not be able to open the app)

Comment: Got a success. :) Follow these steps. 

1 -> Download Sqlite From -> http://www.sqlite.org/2013/sqlite-wp80-winrt-3080000.vsix

2 -> install The vsix.

3 -> Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WP80\3.8.0 

and rename 3.8.0 to 3.8.0.2 See if it works :) 

4 -> Now add the project downloaded from GitHub the C++ one

Comment: The actual binary 3.8.0.2 could not searc if you find out then please post the link :)

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it was searching for the directory `3.8.0.2`. Whereas it is actually `3.8.0` in my machine. I changed it to `3.8.0.2` and I was able to add the `sqlite` project to my solution.

Comment: Check wether the database functionality are working and let me know :)

Comment: I am getting this error when I build the project `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Ok then obviously this work around wont work. Ill search for the 3.8.0.2 sdk for sqlite in wp8. U also carry the same. THe one who finds fast leaves a reply here :) . Looks like some modification has been done in new one. Lets start :)

Comment: Got Success. I removed the previous installed extension from the VS 2012 and installed latest one and it started working like magic. I am now able to build the app. thanks

Comment: Your welcome. but most of the effort was ours(Both) :) Thanks I also got to learn some thing. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Open your Solution in Visual studio.
Click on Tools->Extension and Update 
it will open Extension and Update Browser windows than search Sqlite for windows online and install Sqlite from searched result. than it will restart your SDK

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you will get the same error even when you create every simple Visual C++ windows phone project from VS2012. In this case, I doubt that the issue is related to your VS.

And according to Konrad’s reply in this thread with similar issues: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cba01040-067e-4ac3-ba4c-a8a14ba3c45d/unable-to-read-the-project-file, I feel that you can check if this file: C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v7.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Windows Phone.7.0.targets is on your system. If it is not there, I doubt that your VS installation is wrong.

If you are not using VS Express, you could locate to the IDE folder then run these commands to check if it can help:

```
Please open Windows Explorer, and navigate to  <Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE
Devenv.exe /SafeMode: Launches the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows.
Devenv.exe /ResetSettings: Restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to the specified VSSettings file.
Devenv.exe /ResetAddin: Removes commands and command UI associated with the specified Add-in.
Devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs: Clears all SkipLoading tags added to VSPackages.
```

If no help, I suggest you try repairing your VS or uninstall it and then reinstall it.

Best regards,